# mysql join multiple clauses

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search function where users provide 2 inputs: $studies and $elements. I need to search the database, which in this case has two tables: studies and studies_elements. I want to join these two tables where the search function found a match for both studies and elements. How is my MYSQL query supposed to look? Right now I have this:

```
$studies = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['search-studies']);
$elements = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['search-elements']);

$sql = SELECT S.*, P.* 
       FROM studies S 
           LEFT JOIN studies_elements P 
               ON S.study_id = P.study_id 
               AND S.author LIKE '%$studies%' OR S.study_name LIKE '%$studies%' OR s.abstract LIKE '%$studies%'
               AND P.first_element LIKE '%$elements%' OR P.second_element LIKE '%$elements%' OR P.third_element LIKE '%$elements%'
       ORDER BY S.study_id
```

This code is supposed to produce the merged table, and it does. But it also produces the same result when `$elements` cannot be found in the database. For example, if I pass the values 'john' as `$studies` and 'transaction costs' as `$elements` it gives the exact same results as when I pass 'john' and 'bullshit', even though 'bullshit' is not in P.first_element, P.second_element, or P.third_element. I have tried adding some parentheses in various locations but to no avail.

I need to construct a query that takes these two inputs, checks if they can be joined in a single table, and then retrieves that table.

Comment: use brackets `(` for S table clauses. similarly for P table clauses

Comment: See about prepared and bound queries in PHP, and note that '%...' cannot use an index.

Comment: The problem is *operator precedence*, the order in which `AND` and `OR` are applied. When you write `WHERE Condition1 AND Condition2 OR Condition3`, you will get all rows that matches `Condition1 AND Condition2` as well as all rows that match `Condition3`. In your case you want to enforce a different grouping by adding parentheses: `WHERE Condition1 AND (Condition2 OR Condition3)`. In other words `WHERE StudyCondition AND (..AuthorCondition1 OR AuthorCondition2)  AND (ElementCondition1 OR ElementCondition2 OR ElementCondition3)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use parenthesis() for or condition as you missed it that's why it gives you all combinations of result

```
SELECT S.*, P.* 
       FROM studies S 
           JOIN studies_elements P 
               ON S.study_id = P.study_id 
               AND (S.author LIKE '%$studies%' OR S.study_name LIKE '%$studies%' OR s.abstract LIKE '%$studies%')
               AND (P.first_element LIKE '%$elements%' OR P.second_element LIKE '%$elements%' OR P.third_element LIKE '%$elements%')
       ORDER BY S.study_id
```

Comment: This query just merges all rows in the two tables

Comment: If you change the LEFT JOIN to JOIN, I'll accept it as the answer

Comment: @Vava This is why the question should have had example data, current outcome and desired outcome. I would have given you the same answer if fa06 hadn't beaten me to it, and I can't figure out by your comment what is wrong with it.

Comment: @Vava, agreed with Golez Trol, what is the wrong with inner join, doest it gives you all rows, as we don't know your scenario it's tough to answer based on assumption. Whether you except it as answer or not that's up to you bro :)

Comment: @ ha ha ha, @JuanCarlosOropeza ok as you said :), btw, Golez Trol already updated it in my answer